# Automate .get requests via python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I have [a python script](https://repl.it/repls/CurvyPleasantOctagons) that scrapes a page, uses jinja2 templating engine to output the appropriate HTML that I **finally** got working thanks to you kind folks and the people of The Coding Den Discord.

I'm looking to automate the .get request I'm making at the top of the file.

I have thousands of URLs I want this script to run on. What's a good way to go about this? I've tried using an array of URLs but `requests` says no to that. It complains that must be a string. So it seems I would need to iterate over the `compiledUrls` variable each time. Any advice on the subject would be much appreciated.

Comment: put all the url on a text file, then read it line by line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build a text file with the urls.

**urls.txt**

```
https://www.perfectimprints.com/custom-promos/20267/Pizza-Cutters1.html
https://www.perfectimprints.com/custom-promos/20267/Pizza-Cutters2.html
https://www.perfectimprints.com/custom-promos/20267/Pizza-Cutters3.html
https://www.perfectimprints.com/custom-promos/20267/Pizza-Cutters4.html
https://www.perfectimprints.com/custom-promos/20267/Pizza-Cutters5.html
```

**get urls and process**:

```
with open("urls.txt") as file:
    for single_url in file:
        url = requests.get(single_url.strip())
        ..... # your code continue here
```

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need. Let me try it out. Follow up: I need to save the file I generate at the end of the script to a seperate folder (index.html and products.json to a folder called pizza-cutters). How would I do that?

Comment: `compiledUrls = open("urls.txt").splitlines()
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'splitlines'` The error I'm getting when I try your code.